# How do I link domain name with server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, hosting, web-hosting, mean-stack

I have developed a MEAN stack application. Now I want to host it. I have bought a domain name from BigRock.in and server from Amazon. I am able to run the application on the server and access it like using below URL,

```
ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

But in order to link my domain name with my application I am confused.

After lot of googling I have the below points,

1. Create A Record which maps the domain name with the Elastic IP.

Hence I have created an elastic IP for my instace. Below is the image. But I have no idea where to create this record on BigRock site.

[image]

2. When I mailed to the support team at BigRock they told me that I have to contact Amazon to get the name server details to update in BigRock. But I don't have the priviledge to ask Amazon support since it's a free account.

Below is the Name server screen shot that is where I have to update the name serve details of my server. (Names in the below image are by default.)

[image]

Can some one who has hosted using BigRock + Amazon or someone who has idea about how to get the name server from Amazon and update it BigRock can share their knowledge.

**P.S:** I know it's not a programming question but I am not sure where to post this other than SO.

Answer (score 0):

If the server you selected is free or not that's not a big deal for them. they should provide support to configure their server with the domain you purchased. to do that login to your Amazon account using given login details and open up a 'Support Ticket.' and ask from them about name-servers values and give those into your domain purchased place. they will be configure your domain with the given name servers.

Comment: But when I click on technical support it says,
**"At the Basic Support level, you can create account and billing support cases and service limit increase requests, but you cannot create technical support cases"**